# A parameter property is only allowed in constructor implementation

Tags: angular, typescript

I've written this code and this line `use(private lang: string): Promise<object>` is giving me an error: "A parameter property is only allowed in constructor implementation".

It works when I remove access modifier `private` but I'm just curious why it gives me this error and what is the right way?

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {

  public data: object = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  use(private lang: string): Promise<object> {
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/i18n/${lang || 'en'}.json`;

      this.http.get<object>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
          resolve(this.data);
        },
        error => {
          this.data = {};
          resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove private in

```
use(private lang: string): Promise<object> {
```

`private` and `public` are only used in the class level, not function level (they're always private).

The only function in a class accept `public` or/and `private` is the constructor function, as it will assign values and create properties for the class.